# How do I compare summary statistics for two variables in r (in console, not viewer)?

Tags: r, stargazer

I am trying to do a simple comparison of summary statistics for two variables in R (econmath$act; and econmath$act0). In this chunk of code I create the variable econmath$act0:

```
library('wooldridge')
data(econmath)
econmath$actmiss<-ifelse(is.na(econmath$act),1,0)
econmath$act0<-ifelse(data$actmiss==1,0,data$act)
```

I want to compare summary statistics for econmath$act with econmath$act0. The only way I have found to compare these so far is using the st function from the vtable package. However, I would prefer a solution that can present them in the console. I have tried the following:

```
stargazer(summary(econmath$act),summary(econmath$act0),type="text")
```

But I get the following error message:

```
Error in objects[[i]]$zelig.call :
$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Is there a package/command that I can use that will output comparable summary statistics (on just two variables) to the console, rather than the viewer? I would like to be able to do this in stargazer if possible.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be helpful to provide a reproducible dataset so others can help you. Run `dput(econmath)` and paste the output into your question so people can reproduce your data and help.

Comment: Note that sumtable/st can output to the console if you specify the out = 'return' option. This will return a data.frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. The data

First of all, you don't need to load an entire package to get one of its data sets, `data` has an argument `package`.

```r
data(econmath, package = 'wooldridge')
str(econmath)
#> 'data.frame':    856 obs. of  17 variables:
#>  $ age     : int  23 23 21 22 22 22 22 22 22 21 ...
#>  $ work    : num  15 0 25 30 25 0 20 20 28 22.5 ...
#>  $ study   : num  10 22.5 12 40 15 30 25 15 7 25 ...
#>  $ econhs  : int  0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ colgpa  : num  3.49 2.1 3.09 2.68 3.75 ...
#>  $ hsgpa   : num  3.35 3.22 3.31 3.98 3.89 ...
#>  $ acteng  : int  24 23 21 31 28 25 15 28 28 18 ...
#>  $ actmth  : int  26 20 24 28 31 30 19 30 28 19 ...
#>  $ act     : int  27 24 21 31 32 28 18 32 30 17 ...
#>  $ mathscr : int  10 9 8 10 8 10 9 9 6 9 ...
#>  $ male    : int  1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 ...
#>  $ calculus: int  1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 ...
#>  $ attexc  : int  0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 ...
#>  $ attgood : int  0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 ...
#>  $ fathcoll: int  1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
#>  $ mothcoll: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 ...
#>  $ score   : num  84.4 57.4 66.4 81.2 95.9 ...
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

## 2. A bug corrected.

There was a bug in the question's code, `data$actmiss` and `data$act` refer to a non-existing data set.
Also, in its first use, `ifelse` can be replaced by `as.integer`.

```r
data(econmath, package = 'wooldridge')

econmath$actmiss <- as.integer(is.na(econmath$act))
econmath$act0 <- ifelse(econmath$actmiss == 1L, 0L, econmath$act)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

## 3. The question.

The operator `$` extracts a list member or data.frame column, use `[` and the error is gone, see [Difference between `[` and `[[`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el).

In the code below I create a vector of columns of interest in order to make the code more readable. Then format the summaries with `stargazer`.

**Aren't you looking for the second table?** Instead of explicitly calling `summary` on the objects, argument `summary` gives the best output.

```r
data(econmath, package = 'wooldridge')

econmath$actmiss <- as.integer(is.na(econmath$act))
econmath$act0 <- ifelse(econmath$actmiss == 1L, 0L, econmath$act)

cols <- c("act", "act0")
stargazer::stargazer(summary(econmath[cols]), type = "text")
#> 
#> =========================
#>    act act0      NA      
#> -------------------------
#> 1      act   Min. :13.00 
#> 2      act  1st Qu.:21.00
#> 3      act  Median :23.00
#> 4      act   Mean :23.12 
#> 5      act  3rd Qu.:25.00
#> 6      act   Max. :33.00 
#> 7      act    NA's :42   
#> 8      act0  Min. : 0.00 
#> 9      act0 1st Qu.:20.00
#> 10     act0 Median :23.00
#> 11     act0  Mean :21.99 
#> 12     act0 3rd Qu.:25.00
#> 13     act0  Max. :33.00 
#> 14     act0              
#> -------------------------
stargazer::stargazer(econmath[cols], summary = TRUE, type = "text")
#> 
#> =====================================
#> Statistic  N   Mean  St. Dev. Min Max
#> -------------------------------------
#> act       814 23.122  3.349   13  33 
#> act0      856 21.987  5.970    0  33 
#> -------------------------------------
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Another two ways are

```r
stargazer::stargazer(summary(econmath['act']),
                     summary(econmath['act0']),
                     type = "text")
#> 
#> =======================
#>   act NA      NA.1     
#> -----------------------
#> 1     act  Min. :13.00 
#> 2     act 1st Qu.:21.00
#> 3     act Median :23.00
#> 4     act  Mean :23.12 
#> 5     act 3rd Qu.:25.00
#> 6     act  Max. :33.00 
#> 7     act   NA's :42   
#> -----------------------
#> 
#> =========================
#>   act0  NA      NA.1     
#> -------------------------
#> 1      act0  Min. : 0.00 
#> 2      act0 1st Qu.:20.00
#> 3      act0 Median :23.00
#> 4      act0  Mean :21.99 
#> 5      act0 3rd Qu.:25.00
#> 6      act0  Max. :33.00 
#> -------------------------

stargazer::stargazer(econmath['act'],
                     econmath['act0'],
                     summary = TRUE,
                     type = "text")
#> 
#> =====================================
#> Statistic  N   Mean  St. Dev. Min Max
#> -------------------------------------
#> act       814 23.122  3.349   13  33 
#> -------------------------------------
#> 
#> =====================================
#> Statistic  N   Mean  St. Dev. Min Max
#> -------------------------------------
#> act0      856 21.987  5.970    0  33 
#> -------------------------------------
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>